# ggRadar showing different values than dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggradar

I am fairly new to R and I am working on a radar plot with multiple y-values and facets. I want to create three seperate radar plots out of my dataframe instead of just one, depending on the location of my points. When I filter my df according to the points I want, it is not displayed with the correct values.

```
p.tot <- ggRadar(df.Plot.PI.total, mapping = aes(colour = scenario, facet = PlotNames),
            size=3, alpha = 0, ylim = c(1,1))+
    theme_bw()+
    scale_color_manual(name="Scenario", values = cbPalette.PI)+
    scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette.PI, name="Scenario")+
    labs(title = "Changes in Protection Indexes")+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20,face = "bold"),
          strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
          legend.title = element_text(face="bold",size = 18), legend.text = element_text(size = 16),
          legend.position = "bottom",
          text = element_text(size=18),
          axis.text = element_text(size=14),axis.title = element_text(size=14))
```

[image]

Plotting the whole df worked fine. For my work I want to plot three different plots, one for each group of points. So I applied a filter to the df to only plot the points of interest.

```
df.Plot.PI.SUB <- df.Plot.PI.total %>% filter(str_detect(PlotNames, "SUB_"))
```

When I plot the shortened data however, some points in the radarplots are not displayed correctly, even though the data is still the same!

[image]

Can somebody tell how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `ggRadar` by default rescales all continuous variables in the dataset (see `?ggRadar`):

> *rescale* A logical value. If TRUE, all continuous variables in the data.frame are rescaled.

As the rescaling depends on the data provided you will get a different result when subsetting your data. To fix that rescale your data manually and set `rescale=FALSE`.

As you provided no example data I created a minimal reprex based on mtcars.

First I reproduce your issue with the default rescaling. Here we get different plots when dropping the `cyl=8` values.

```r
library(ggiraphExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

mtcars_radar <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "group") %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl),
         across(!c(group, cyl), rescale)) %>% 
  tail(4) %>% 
  select(1:10)

p1 <- ggRadar(mtcars_radar, mapping = aes(facet = cyl))
p2 <- ggRadar(filter(mtcars_radar, cyl != 8), mapping = aes(facet = cyl))


p1 / p2
```

[image]

But when setting `rescale=FALSE` we get the same radar charts for `cyl=4` and `cyl=6`:

```r
p3 <- ggRadar(mtcars_radar, mapping = aes(facet = cyl), rescale = FALSE)

p4 <- ggRadar(filter(mtcars_radar, cyl != 8), mapping = aes(facet = cyl), rescale = FALSE)

p3 / p4
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved it. I've spend so much time on this, obviously the solution was simple! Cheers!